# How to Convert ADO.NET to LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql

```
"SELECT TOP " + this.mintPageSize + " * FROM tblGroupDetail WHERE GroupDetailId NOT IN " + "(SELECT TOP " + intSkip + " GroupDetailId FROM tblGroupDetail)")
```

How Convert this Query to Linq.SomeOne tell me with Code?i have tried

var innerQuery = (from fb in db.tblGroupDetails where fb.GroupDetailID  select fb).Take(this.mintPageSize);
                       var result = from f in db.tblGroupDetails where innerQuery.Contains(f.GroupDetailID) select f;

Comment: Well what have you tried so far, and what was the result? You'll want to use `Take`.

Comment: I am working on paging in datagridView this query Works efficiently in ADO.NET. but convert in Linq , i have tried many times.

Comment: So show what you've tried, and explain what didn't work. Note that "TOP" without an ordering is far from ideal. You may find that just Skip and Take do what you want.

Comment: var innerQuery = (from fb in db.tblGroupDetails where fb.GroupDetailID  select fb).Take(this.mintPageSize);
                        var result = from f in db.tblGroupDetails where innerQuery.Contains(f.GroupDetailID) select f;

Comment: No, don't add it as a comment - edit your question. Although I've given a potential answer anyway.

Comment: @MuhammadNafees Try to go with Jon's answer, replace `.OrderBy(...)` with `.OrderBy(o => o.GroupDetailId)` if you're not sure what to do with ordering, and see if that giving you the expected result. If it is not, edit your question reporting further problem you had with latest code you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you just need:

```
var query = db.GroupDetail
              .OrderBy(...) // You really need an ordering
              .Skip(intSkip)
              .Take(mintPageSize);
```

You should work out what ordering you want, otherwise "the first N" doesn't have any meaning.

That's not a translation of your query so much as your *intent* - you should check what SQL it generates.